# Plot based on different date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

i've written the following code that plots the relative bpm for the various hours contained in the csv given in input, for a given date.

```
dfMonday['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfMonday['date'])
df_temp = dfMonday.loc[dfMonday['date'] == '2021/04/26']

bpmMon = df_temp.tempo
hMon = df_temp.time
x = '26/04/2021'

meanBpmMon = bpmMon .mean()
    
second = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.title('HOURS - BPM (MONDAY- 26/04/2021)')
plt.scatter(hMon , bpmMon , c = bpmMon)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Within the CSV I have other dates, all different from each other, which refer to other days of listening to music. What I would like to do is create more charts based on the date which is contained in the csv. In detail: if I have other n dates I would like to output n graphs based on the date contained in the csv.

Csv file have the following structure:

```
artist_name;ms_played;track_name;...date;time;week_day
Taylor Swift;35260;Wildest Dreams;...;2021-01-25;07:55;0
Edward Sharpe & The Magnetic Zeros;...2021-01-25;15:34;0
Kanye West; 127964; ...; 2021-02-21;08:08;0
Billie Eilish; 125412; ...; 2021-15-2; 15:02; 0
......
```

As you can see from the date column, I have several dates inside the csv

Comment: I don't know why you ask the same question again. I gave you yesterday a link to an excellent explanation of the options you have to distribute your data into subplots. Idk why you deleted this question and posted a duplicate question. What have you tried to implement any of these four options, and what were the specific problems arising from this implementation?

Comment: I've asked the question again bc the link you gave me yesterday didn't help me, so i decided to post the same question in other way thinking that someone else could help me. Thanks anyway for helping me, I appreciate that.